# Infinite path route into an ASP.NET Core action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I want create a route which routes an infinite collection of strings in url.

Like this:

```
https://github.com/{orgName}/{projectName}/blob/{branchName}/{folderName1}/{folderName2}/.../{folderNameN}/{fileName}
```

For eample

```
https://github.com/AiursoftWeb/Nexus/blob/master/Account/Controllers/AccountController.cs
```

Will be routed to this action. And route result shall be:

```
orgName: AiursoftWeb
projectName: Nexus
branchName: master
folderNames: string[2] of:
    "Account"
    "Controllers"
fileName: AccountController.cs
```

How do I achieve that?

I have tried the following way:

```cs
[Route("Folders/ViewContent/{siteName}/{folderNames}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewContent(string siteName, params string[] folderNames)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you just trying to return static files? Because just using StaticFilesMiddleware would be much easier.

Comment: @Valuator Nope. I am creating an API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the asterisk character to denote a placeholder in the route template as a catch-all parameter. You do then have to split this parameter into folder names yourself:

```
[Route("Folders/ViewContent/{siteName}/{*folderNames}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewContent(string siteName, string folderNames)
{
    folderNames = folderNames ?? "";
    string[] folders = folderNames.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     // your other code
}
```

Starting with ASP.net Core 2.2 you should use double asterisk so that urls generated automatically will not url-escape the slashes in the url:

```
[Route("Folders/ViewContent/{siteName}/{**folderNames}")]
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> You can use an asterisk (`*`) or double asterisk (`**`) as a prefix to a
>   route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI. These are called a
>   *catch-all* parameters. For example, `blog/{**slug}` matches any URI that
>   starts with `/blog` and has any value following it, which is assigned to
>   the `slug` route value. Catch-all parameters can also match the empty
>   string.
>
> The catch-all parameter escapes the appropriate characters when the
>   route is used to generate a URL, including path separator (`/`)
>   characters. For example, the route `foo/{*path}` with route values `{`
>   `path = "my/path" }` generates `foo/my%2Fpath`. Note the escaped forward
>   slash. To round-trip path separator characters, use the `**` route
>   parameter prefix. The route `foo/{**path}` with `{ path = "my/path" }`
>   generates `foo/my/path`.

Comment: The difference is whether forward slashes are url-escpaed or not when the url is generated automatically by the framework. I believe this is already explained in detail in the quoted text

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 constraint in your routing which lead to exactly match from the URL. Are you sure your url start with "Folders/ViewContent/". You have 6 folder name in your URL according your question but your routing only handle 4 folder that deeeper. Write the routing to match that folder by passing more foldername (or placeholder for folder).

For better debugging you can pass the whole url as static and change one by one to better debug your routing.

Comment: The folder levels can be infinite. Which means that even 10 levels of folders shall be routed to this action and all folder names shall be passed to it.

Comment: check this https://tommyb.com/blog/customizing-asp-net-cores-route-constraints-and-model-binding/ and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.irouteconstraint?view=aspnetcore-2.2